# Android Open Source Business Card Reader

Tags: android, open-source, ocr, business-card

What open source business card reader applications are available for Android?

I would like to be able to snap a picture of the card or scan it and import it into my contacts/address book.

I would prefer not to depend on the business card format, using a QR code or any other specific technology dependency.

Answer (score 1):

No single open source app exists, but a unified workflow does:

1. Open [OCR Test](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=ocr&fdid=edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr)
2. Use the integrated picture-taking option for [Open Note Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todobom.opennotescanner) to scan your document and feed that picture back to OCR Test.
3. Long-press to copy recognized text and paste it into your vcard creator software.

Comment: ocr test link is dead, seems to be no longer on fdroid but apparently on google play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.
Also can you give an example for the vcard creator software?